# Track scrubbing in webkit controller based on time control is clicked and held?

Tags: javascript, webkit

What I'm essentially trying to accomplish is track scrubbing in a webkit controller. What I'd like to do is set the onClick function to skip forward or back when the appropriate directional button is clicked, but also scrub backwards or forwards if the control is clicked and held.

However, I'm thoroughly stuck on the JS necessary to not only differentiate the clicks and click holds but also measure the time held. Once the time held is determined, it should be as simple as setting time to iTunes.playerPosition +/- clicktime

For the onclick event, do I simply use settimeout to determine the difference between clicking and clicking and holding?

Also, how would I measure the time held using javascript?

I apologize for the vagueness of my question, but I'm a bit new to JS and any help you can provide would be hugely, hugely appreciated. If more details are needed, I will do my best to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about onClick, but I'd use onMouseDown and onMouseUp. You would set the time onMouseDown that dragging has started, and check that flagged time onMouseUp.